# Sources Appear Mysteriously

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, web

I thought I understood how browsers work, but it seems not. :(

Given a web page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="scripts/main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Served locally by nodejs, the Network panel:

[image]

Okay, right. But there's a bunch more Sources *not* appearing in Network activity:

[image]

How do they get there? I see no references to `src/scripts/main.jsx` or `/node_modules` in `main.js` or anywhere else.

**BACKGROUND**
This is certainly due to some error in my gulp build, specifically with browserify (and babel/react). I'm doing something wrong there, but I'm much more troubled that I cannot understand how these sources are turning up in my browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A discrepancy here is most likely due to [source maps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/). From the sources tab, click the menu icon in the top right and select settings. From here uncheck "Enable JavaScript source maps" and refresh to see if this is indeed the culprit.

[image]

Comment: I has mistaken thought these "mysterious" files were messing up my site. I read up on source maps, and now I get it. It learned that browserify's ```debug``` switch turns on source maps. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. Glad you got it worked out